# Bug: Linkcolor of visited badges on mobile

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

If I click on the "newest" badge in my profil on my desktop PC browser (firefox) the detail page opens and the link color of the badge text is still white, when going back to my profile.

When I do the same on my mobile (iOS, safari) I got a dark blue visited link color for badges which makes the name of the badge very hard to read. I think the visited-link color of one of these CSS-classes is wrong on mobile:

```
<div class="subtitle"> Newest </div>
  <span class="badge-container">
    <span id="badge-card-last">
      <a class="badge" href="/help/badges/900/quorum?userid=2154300">
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Please see Screenshot:

[image: Profile on mobile with dark blue visited link color]

Comment: reported on mse already.

Comment: I keep forgetting to see if I need to report this. May be a dupe still though.

Comment: @nicael: so? It's fine to report it on individual Meta sites too.

Comment: Hm I tried to search (here and on mse) for it with `visited link color` and combinations of `link`, `badge` and `color` but I didn't find anything. So sorry if already reported.

Comment: [MSE cross-site dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258737/badges-are-sometimes-unreadable-in-mobile-theme) of this question.  Still unfixed.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to have been fixed in the updated mobile design.

The link colour does not change when the link is clicked.